# Blender Object Mode Transform Dimensions Vs. Edit mode dimensions

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-printing

My object is square with respect to X and Y. In object mode, I  changed the X and Y dimensions in the Transform drop down. I made X and Y smaller by two millimeters. When I went back into edit mode and checked the X and Y measurements of my object’s square base, the measurements were the same as before I changed the dimensions.

I need to make the measurements I see in edit mode smaller by 2mm. I expected them to change when I lowered the dimensions.

When I change the dimensions from the transform menu, what is that actually changing? Does it affect measurements in edit mode? Or is it just changing the scale of the object?

Comment: Hi. In Object mode you need to press Ctrl->A and click Scale to reset the scale to 1. The scale was changed when you changed the dimensions in the dropdown.